# How to choose data range in python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have problem when I use    `.mean` to calculate value of mean in csv file. I use `.read` to read my csv it looks like:

```
       Adj Close
0      0.007427
1      0.002013
2      0.008874
3      0.006018
...    .....
999    NaN
```

when I `.mean` to calculate, the result is different with the one which calculate by excel. So I am wondering is that "NaN" or "Adj Close" affect my result? And how to make it right to get correct result?

```
Adj = pd.read_csv('XXXX.csv', usecols=["Adj Close"])
```

this is how I read my csv file. Thanks in advance！

Comment: I don't know off top of my head how excel does it.  But see if `Adj.fillna(0).mean()` matches.

Comment: Adj Close is this first line in my csv file。

Answer (score 0):

If you are are iterating over the rows in Pandas, it probably skips the values with NaN, while in excel it takes it as "0" when makes the calculation